# Client Architecture - Data Layer, MV* and coupling

Tags: android, mvvm, architecture, model, mvp

I've been researching best practices for client architectures for a while now, including mvvm and the latest additions such as flux...

I'm considering the architecture for an android app, which will probably use a combination of mvvm and mvp for presentational purposes.

The thing that troubles me is coupling between components (mv* related classes),
for example:
I have a SlimStockItem model used in StockListView, which enables navigation to a StockItem used in a StockItemView, StockItem has more data.

I could use the same StockItem with null values for both views - this would introduce coupling between the controllers and views of the list and item details components or using a different approach which results in a couple of implementation choices:

1. Have a "domain" entity called Stock which has all the data and construct the relevant StockItem from it's "repository"
2. Don't implement a domain layer at all and query the server for StockItem (implement caching if appropriate at a technical layer)
3. Keep the coupling and pass StockItem to the stock item view.

The second scenario is receiving an update (push/pull) for a Stock from the server.

(Flux) Events are really good as a pub/sub implementation to inform multiple view of new state changes originating from user interactions/server push/pull interactions.

When considering the implementation, I have couple of choices:
1. Update the "domain" layer and publish a downstream event "StockUpdated" with the "domain" model Stock as payload for the mv* components to update SlimStockItem and StockItem.
2. Don't implement a domain layer at all and publish an event "StockUpdated" with a StockDataPayload for the mv* components to update SlimStockItem and StockItem.

Which approach do you use and what are the potential tradeoffs? (If you use a different approach then please describe it!)

P.S i'm quoting "domain" model, because the actual domain model resides at the server and is out of scope when discussing client architecture.

Best regards,
Erik.